# Clang OS X compiler balks on this code but it works fine on Linux

Tags: macos, c++11, boost, linker, clang

The following sample code works fine under linux using g++4.8.2, using boost1_56. However, I get a strange linker error under MacOS X (Yosemite) using clang:

```
ld: internal error: atom not found in symbolIndex(__ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeIKNS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEN15FRUIT_TUPLES4dataEEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIS8_SB_NS9_8key_hashELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIS8_SB_NS9_9key_equalELb1EEENS5_ISB_EEE15__insert_uniqueIRKNS_4pairIS8_SA_EEEENSL_INS_15__hash_iteratorIPNS_11__hash_nodeISB_PvEEEEbEEOT_) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Proces
```

The main.cpp file

```
#include "TupleFruits.hpp"

int main()
{
    map_t fruitHash = InitializeFruitHash();

    std::string fruit = "BANANA";

    auto itr = fruitHash(fruit);
    if (fruitHash.end() == itr)
    {
        std::cout << fruit << " not found in hash" << std::endl;

        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The FruitHash.cpp file:

```
#include "TupleFruits.hpp"

map_t InitializeFruitHash()
{
    static map_t m;

    data dBANANA = {0, 0, 6, false};
    data dGRAPEFRUIT = {1, 1, 6, false};
    data dSTRAWBERRY = {2, 2, 6, false};

    m[BANANA] = dBANANA;
    m[GRAPEFRUIT] = dGRAPEFRUIT;
    m[STRAWBERRY] = dSTRAWBERRY;

    return m;
}
```

The include file "HashData.hpp

```
#ifndef HASH_DATA_HPP
#define HASH_DATA_HPP

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

typedef std::string fruit_key_t;

namespace HASH_TUPLES
{
struct key_hash : public std::unary_function<fruit_key_t, std::size_t>
{
    std::size_t operator()(const fruit_key_t& k) const
    {
        std::hash<std::string> hash_fn;

        return hash_fn(k);
    }
};

struct key_equal : public std::binary_function<fruit_key_t, fruit_key_t, bool>
{
    bool operator()(const fruit_key_t& v0, const fruit_key_t& v1) const
    {
        return (v0 == v1);
    }
};

struct data
{
    int row;
    int column;
    int precision;
    bool isRipe;

    inline bool operator ==(data d)
    {
       if (d.row == row && d.column == column)
          return true;
       else
          return false;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const data& rhs)    //Overloaded operator for '<<'
    {                                                                       //for struct output
        os  << rhs.row << ", "
            << rhs.column;

        return os;
    }
};

typedef std::unordered_map<const fruit_key_t, data, key_hash, key_equal> map_t;
//                                                     ^ this is our custom hash

}

template<class T>
struct map_data_compare : public std::binary_function<typename T::value_type,
                                                      typename T::mapped_type,
                                                      bool>
{
public:
    bool operator() (typename T::value_type &pair,
                     typename T::mapped_type i) const
    {
        return pair.second == i;
    }
};

#endif
```

The include file "TupleFruits.hpp"

```
#ifndef TUPLESFRUITS_HPP
#define TUPLESFRUITS_HPP

#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>

#include "HashData.hpp"

using namespace HASH_TUPLES;

map_t InitializeFruitHash();

static std::string BANANA = "banana";
static std::string GRAPEFRUIT = "grapefruit";
static std::string STRAWBERRY = "strawberry";

#endif
```

Comment: This is just a standard linker error, you have missed an object file out

Comment: It does feel like I am missing a library from the link step, I just can't figure out what it is! I don't need to add anything in the linux version. The only thing I took out from the link step is -rt

Comment: well, where is InitializeFruitHash?

Comment: In FruitHash.cpp file

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Somehow -s (strip all symbols from binary) snuck in my Makefile